# Change default database of Bonita 6.5

Tags: mysql, database, bonita

I am using bonita 6.5 and I would like to change the organizational database : users , roles , tasks , permissions...(not data) of bonita to my mysql database.
I've followed the official documentation but then I realised that it's maybe for data and I wonder if that's true !

1) If it's for data then how can I change the oraginzational DB ?

2) Otherwise , how can bonita "know" that I have users ... in that DB ?  what are the changes that I have to make ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run, Bonita BPM will need a copy of your users in its database.

If your organization is stored in your own database, you will have to create a synchronization tool to replicate at least the users (not necessarily the groups and roles) with the Bonita APIs.
Note that such a [tool](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/ldap-synchronizer-2) exists in the Subscription edition to replicate users and groups from LDAP or AD.

Then, in order to deal with the "authorization" aspect (or rather human task dispatch), you can use [custom actor filters](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/software-extensibility-0#actor_filters) to assign tasks based on external systems such as your own database.

Just to let you know, the most efficient way to go is to synchronize everything (users, groups and roles) then use [actors](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/actors-0) when possible or actor filters if necessary.

Hope this helps,